# Corrupted revision after bad merge

Tags: version-control, mercurial

yesterday I tried to merge a fork and my main branch for a school project. What I usually do is:

1. Clone my main branch
2. Merge them
3. If successful pull the commit of the new branch which was used to merge, if unsuccessful restart

When I did merge the forked branch and the main one, I skipped (or forgot) to merge using a test branch. I guess you figure out what happened, I made mistakes when executing commands and was unsuccessful in my merge, by the time I noticed that, I had already committed.

Now here's a list of what I know:

- The clean version of the branch is rev 30
- I am unable to clone rev 30 as I receive this: `abort: data/inc/presentation/view/PageIndexV.php.i@fc3df292e283: no node!`
- I have 3 heads for some reason.
- I have tried to do `hg update -r 30`
- I tried to revert too

These are my heads

```
changeset:   35:cf4f3f8519d2
tag:         tip
parent:      30:fdb11c78eb12
user:        Alexandre * <*@gmail.com>
date:        Sat Jun 08 19:07:31 2013 -0400
files:       .htaccess
description:
Modif .htaccess

changeset:   34:331201eaa5e2
parent:      30:fdb11c78eb12
user:        Alexandre * <*@gmail.com>
date:        Sat Jun 08 18:55:19 2013 -0400
files:       inc/presentation/view/PageIndexV.php
description:
Test

changeset:   33:6f6f6d4226da
user:        Alexandre * <*@gmail.com>
date:        Sat Jun 08 18:04:11 2013 -0400
description:
Close branch
```

Rev 33 was where I tried doing hg commit --close-branch
On Rev 34 I thought maybe adding back the file it's complaining about would help so I added it back (it was not needed anymore so it was deleted)
On rev 35, cpanel had modified .htaccess so I committed it and for some reason it made a new head for no reason...

If any other bit info is needed, just ask, I'll gladly provide it.
I really want to go back or get a copy of revision 30, every bit of info is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I ended up doing:

1. I deleted the .hg folder
2. Did `hg init` again
3. then force the pull as they were now unrelated using hg pull -f